# Python Recursion inside Inherited Class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a class and a method:

```py
class Demo(dict):

  def foo(self, key):
     bar = self[key]
     foo(bar, key)
```

Class `Demo` accepts a `dict` as an argument
 
From `app.py` I'm calling `Demo` as:

```py
data = { 'a': { 'a' : 123 } }

Demo(data).foo('a')
```

My question is, how do I pass the newly formed dictionary `bar = self[key]` as an argument to `foo()` while recursing?

Should I use this instead ?:

```py
class Demo():

  def foo(self, data, key):
     bar = data[key]
     foo(bar, key)
```

Is there any other better approach?

Comment: @Carcigenicate That would certainly help. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: At the very least, you have to write `Demo.foo(bar, key)`, since you don't want a *global* `foo`, but the class attribute by that name.

Comment: It's also not clear from this example alone why `foo` isn't a static method or a regular function.

Comment: Were you expecting your class to take dict as an argument or did you mean to inherit from dict as you do above?

Comment: @Sayse I'm expecting the class to take `dict` as an argument

Comment: Thought so, that isn't what you're doing, you've inherited from dict and its by pure chance this is working since dict can take another dict in its constructor. Its unclear exactly what you're actually trying to do though

Comment: @Sayse My exact use-case is to accept a `dict` and then perform some read/write operations on it. Hence, I created a `class` which inherits `dict`, and there are methods to `update()`,  `remove()`, ..   values from the passed `dict`. Is this the right approach? Is there a better approach?

Comment: I still don't understand what exactly it is you're doing but hopefully the other answers solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an inner recursive function instead:

```
def foo(self, key):
    def inner(new_d):
        bar = new_d[key]
        inner(bar)

    inner(self)  # Or whatever you want to be the initial value
```

Note how it formed a closure over `key` so that doesn't need to be passed constantly. It can just be accessed from the outer scope.

Of course this function doesn't really make much sense though since it will recurse forever, so I'm assuming this is a stripped down example.

Comment: Using closure seems a great idea. I will definitely try this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It IS possible to do what you want, although I don't know if it's the best solution. It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

The following code, recurses the way you want. The advantage is (if you want it) that the `self.data` parameter in the root class (self) changes throughout the recusion. This is good is you WANT that data to change (for example for later access to the changed data by another method later.)

```
class Demo(dict):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def foo(self, key):
        try:
            self.data = self.data[key]
            return self.foo(key)
        except:
            return self.data

data = { 'a': { 'a' : 123 } }

print(Demo(data).foo('a'))
```

If you DON'T want the `self.data` to be permanently changed, you should use the second method, were `data` and `key` are passed into the function together, and do not affect the `self.data`... or the other answer (about `inner recursive function` by @Carcigenicate)

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo` method needs to be called on an instance of `Demo`, not by itself. In both versions of your code, calling `foo` without looking it up in something (probably an instance) is an error.

Perhaps you want:

```
def foo(self, key):
    obj = Demo(self[key])
    obj.foo(key)
```

This will work for as long as your data has nested dictionaries under the same key. It will fail when `self[key]` doesn't return a dictionary. Presumably you want to have a base case to handle that:

```
def foo(self, key):
    value = self[key]  # you might want a further base case to handle the key not existing at all!
    if not isinstance(value, dict):
        pass           # if you have something to do for the base case, do it here
    else:              # recursive case
        obj = Demo(value)
        obj.foo(key)
```

Now, this class is a bit silly, it copies lots of stuff just so that you can have a method that runs on a `dict`. A much more sensable approach would get rid of the class and just use a recursive function with two arguments, and you'd have no need for creating `obj` in the recursive case:

```
# this foo is a top-level function, not part of a class!
def foo(data, key):  # no self argument any more
    value = data[key]
    ...
    foo(value, key)  # recursive call is simpler now
```

Comment: The second approach without the class would be much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate a new instance of the same class with the sub-dict to recursively traverse down the dict with the same key:

```
class Demo(dict):
    def foo(self, key):
        if isinstance(self[key], dict):
            return self.__class__(self[key]).foo(key)
        return self[key]
```

so that:

```
data = {'a': {'a': 123}}
print(Demo(data).foo('a'))
```

outputs:

```
123
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/PassionateOddAssembly